# Is there a high performance JDBC backed JMS broker?

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, jms

I have an application that makes heavy use of JMS (OpenMQ at the moment).  We need durable persistence on some of the messages in flight, and that needs to survive the database blowing up, so we've moved the broker's storage to JDBC as it means that we can replicate and back up a database cluster and know that both the relational and message stores are at the same point in time when restoring from a backup.

We're finding that OpenMQ's JDBC backed storage method is very slow (tens of messages/s).  Are there any brokers out there that perform well using JDBC?  We're ideally after thousands of messages/s, but can probably tolerate 100s/s.

Comment: I've tested ActiveMQ and works like a charm. Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated to Apache ActiveMQ, just a happy user of the technology.

Comment: Same here. I've used ActiveMQ with JDBC persistence over Oracle for Java serialized messages (around a few tens to hundreds kbs each), and achived peak performance in the thousands/sec - albeit not with XA transactions. It was a few years back, though, I don't have specifics anymore to give a full reply.

Answer (score 0):

Backing a messaging server with JDBC is never going to be as fast using an optimized message store. Most of the time, a broker simply writes messages to disk but do not read. A traditional database is often more optimized towards read performance and complex queries than maximum write performance.

[ActiveMQ with replicated LevelDB](http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html) seems to be a decent fit for your requirements. It will automatically replicate the message store to "slave" brokers while still allow high throughput.

Another option would be to dig into the database part rather than the broker part. You will probably notice similar patterns with other brokers as well, if you hook them up to JDBC. Is there a way to make your database work more efficient with write performance? SSD disks? Settings? etc. As I said, by default, most databases are tweaked towards read performance and performance of complex queries.